# drupal_mail() and names with apostrophes

Tags: 7, emails

When using drupal_mail to send an email, I get errors when display names (not emails) contain apostrophes in the "To" field.

For example, referring to [drupal_mail() documentation](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes--mail.inc/function/drupal_mail/7), email addresses like "`Another User <anotheruser@example.com>`" are valid. "`Another User <anotheruser@example.com>`" validates perfectly, but "`Another O'Neil <anotheroneil@example.com>`" fails.

Do I need to change the last name to ONeil instead of O'Neil, or can escape it somehow?
I have also tried "`"Another O'Neil" <anotheroneil@example.com>`" without success.

- Setup: Ubuntu 11.04 LTS
- Drupal Version: 7.x
- Mail Service: Amazon SES
- Additional Mail Modules: "HTML Mail" and "Mail System"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I assume a few things:

- You have no exotic mail transport installed, having Drupal fallback to phps' [mail()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mail.php)
- You deliver the mail trough a unix system. Windows deals differently with mail.

Digging into [RFC2822](http://www.faqs.org/rfcs/rfc2822.html) you will find about escaping " and some other characters.

The solution then presents itself as

```
$to = "\"Another O'Neil\" <anotheroneil@example.com>";
drupal_mail('contact', 'page_mail', $to, language_default(), $values, $from);

print $to; #=> "Another O'Neil" <anotheroneil@example.com>
```

Comment: Good assumptions. :)  Will add to original question in a moment for future searchers.  An elegant solution to an annoying problem. Thank you. :)